# wp-admin send 404 error

Tags: plugins, 404-error, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I installed the plugin "yoast seo" and now when I enter and exit, they give me an error. And I can only come through /wp-login.php. how to fix ? please help

Comment: If you can't deactivate the plugin using the standard plugins admin page, you can try (via FTP/cPanel) renaming the plugin folder to force deactivation of the plugin. But for support on using the plugin, please consult the plugin support forums/site/docs.

Comment: I do this, but I'm talking about the fact that I need this particular plugin

Comment: Try asking/searching on the plugin support forums/site - someone using the plugin may have encountered the same issue and you could try their solution. Or if you can access the admin pages, you may be lucky just by resetting your permalinks - just visit the permalink settings page.

Answer (score 1):

...what @sally_CJ said in the comment to your question.

In general, if a plugin is causing problems, then remove the plugin. If you can't do that with admin/plugins, then use your hosting File Manager or FTP to rename that plugin's folder, which will effectively disable it.

Also, ensure that PHP is at least version 7.2, and ensure WP and all themes/plugins are updated.

Comment: I do this, but I'm talking about the fact that I need this particular plugin

Comment: Then contact the plugin support page. That's where your question should be asked. You can disable the plugin temporarily by using the 'rename' process. Then ask your question on the plugin's support forum.